# How can I draw a straight line in jfreechart?

Tags: line, jfreechart

How could I draw a straight line with the equation `y=m*x+n` in a jfreechart chart?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds simple enough ... I've never used it, but there is a [XYPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/XYPlot.html) class which sounds like a decent place to start. You can create one using the [ChartFactory](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createScatterPlot%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), to make it a bit easier. You will need to implement a class that implements the [XYDataSet](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html) interface, to return the actual points (i.e. evalutate your equation).

Comment: By default XYPlot draws line(s) between the specified datapoints, so for a straight line you only need to specify two points. For instance (0, n) and (1, m+n).